# find roots of cubic polynomial

Tags: c#, polynomials, math.net, cubic

I'm trying to find the roots of a cubic polynomial `ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0` using math.numerics. The package is great, but I'm struggling to get started with it. Please can someone explain how to find the roots, and a simple explanation on how to run the sample package from [Github](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics)?

I've added a reference to the package

```
using MathNet.Numerics;
```

and this is what I've tried:

```
var roots = FindRoots.Cubic(d, c, b, a);
double root1=roots.item1;
double root2=roots.item2;
double root3=roots.item3;
```

but I get an error `"The type 'Complex' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Numerics'"`. Adding using System.Numerics gives an error and doesn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: you need to input the code in the top most part  Using System.Numerics

Comment: that's where I put it, along with all the other assemblies, directly below ``using MathNet.Numerics``. Intellisense says the assembly is not required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, you need to right-click the References folder for your project in Solution Explorer, click Add Reference, and then select **System.Numerics** from the Assemblies > Framework list:

[image: Screenshot of Reference Manager dialog box]

Because [MathNet.Numerics.FindRoots.Cubic](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/FindRoots.htm#Cubic) returns roots as complex numbers, you must use the [System.Numerics.Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx) type instead of `double` to store your roots:

```
using System.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double d = 0, c = -1, b = 0, a = 1; // x^3 - x
        var roots = FindRoots.Cubic(d, c, b, a);
        Complex root1 = roots.Item1;
        Complex root2 = roots.Item2;
        Complex root3 = roots.Item3;
    }
}
```

If you only want to deal with real numbers, call [MathNet.Numerics.RootFinding.Cubic.RealRoots](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.RootFinding/Cubic.htm) instead (which will return any complex-valued roots as [Double.NaN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
using MathNet.Numerics.RootFinding;
...
var roots = Cubic.RealRoots(d, c, b); // "a" is assumed to be 1
double root1 = roots.Item1;
double root2 = roots.Item2;
double roo13 = roots.Item3;
```

Comment: Yes, he tried that, but "it gave an error". *rolleyes*

Comment: @Blorgbeard: The OP stated that he added `using System.Numerics;` to his code file, instead of adding a reference to the project.

Comment: "Adding using System.Numerics gives an error and doesn't solve the problem."

Comment: Oh, beg your pardon, just read that again, you're right - lol.

Comment: I've added the reference as Michael suggested and the compile error has gone. I was just adding the ``using ...`` line to the top of the class - sorry I should have been clearer. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll also try using complex instead of double.

Comment: thanks,it works! Can you explain how can I use the sample package from GitHub? I can't compile and run it.

Comment: @Zeus: What happens when you try to compile and run it?

Comment: @Michael - if I open ``Examples.sln`` and click ``Start`` in debug or release mode I get an error saying ``"A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly"``. I'm doing something wrong, but this is new to me so I'm not sure what I should be doing.

Comment: @Michael - do you know where I can download a manual on the package's various functions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996140/math-net-numerics-how-to-run-examples and http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/

Comment: Needs reference to MathNet.Numerics